# How to remove "Sign out from facebook" in v-facebook-login plugin

Tags: vue.js, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've been having trouble removing this `Sign out from facebook text if the user is already logged-in on Facebook.
They still need to click sign out and sign-in again in order for them to login to the site. How do I remove it?
This is the code below:

```
        <v-facebook-login
         v-if="fbAppID"
          v-model="facebook.model"
          :app-id="fbAppID"
          :login-options="fbScope"
          :logout="false"
          class="mt-3 fb-login-btn"
          @login="loggedInFb"
          @connect="handleConnect"
          @sdk-init="handleSdkInit"
          @click="handleClick"
        ><span slot="login">Continue with facebook</span>
        </v-facebook-login>`
```

[image]

Comment: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/using+fb+login+with+angular+app - Follow this link. Sample code is here for you

Comment: this is angular I can't seem to follow the components and the plugin I'm using on this one is v-facebook-login

Answer (score 0):

You are using named slots incorrecly.

The property (vue directive) should be:
`v-slot:` instead of `slot=`.

Check the docs:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots

Comment: nah I tried everything but nothing worked, the v-facebook-plugin docs itself lacks info.

Comment: In this way?
https://github.com/adi518/vue-facebook-login-component/issues/6#issuecomment-495895682

Comment: My docs document the slots API and assume you know how to use Vue. Most issues on my repository are from users who didn't read the Vue docs. ;)